# special character in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, special-characters

I have this line :

```
mySharedObject.data.theDate = "25/12/15";
```

and if I do a trace, it returns

> 25%2F12%2F15

How do I make it return:

> 25/12/15

(the "/" is translate by %2F" obviously...)

---

**EDIT**

It's the variable that I'm trying to send that returns : `25%2F12%2F15`

Here's my code :

```
mySharedObject.data.theDate = "25/12/15";
    trace(mySharedObject.data.theDate);


urlVars.thedate = mySharedObject.data.theDate;
    urlReq.data = urlVars;  
    trace(urlReq.data);
```

So the `trace(mySharedObject.data.theDate);` returns : `25/12/15`   PERFECT !

the `trace(urlReq.data);` returns : `thedate=25%2F12%2F15`    ???

Any idea what is the problem ?

---

EDIT 2 :

Here's my function :

```
function sendDataToPHP(evt:Event):void {

    // Create a new URLRequest instance sending data to "scriptmareev2.php"
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("scriptmareev2.php");

    // Send data using the POST method
    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 


    // The data property of the request is set to the
    // URLVariables instance (urlVars) to send to the PHP file.
    // Note: urlVars stored the variable (e.g. candidate)
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 

    urlVars.theport = mySharedObject.data.theCity;

    urlVars.thedate = mySharedObject.data.theDate;


    urlReq.data = urlVars;  
    decodeURIComponent(String(urlReq.data));
    trace(urlReq.data);


    // Create a new instance of the URLLoader class to work with.
    // URLLoader.load( ) method should be used when we need the 
    // sent variables returned back to Flash ActionScript.

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq); 
    //specify dataFormat property of the URLLoader to be "VARIABLES"
    //This ensure that the variables loaded into Flash with the same variable names

    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 

    //Load the PHP file by using URLRequest

    loader.load(urlReq); 
    trace(loader.dataFormat);

    //Listen when the loading of data COMPLETE
    //Call the loadComplete function when the loading COMPLETE
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
}
```

Comment: Nope. It returns `25%2F%2F12%2F%2F15`

Comment: I edited your question, but please clarify that you do actually have the quotes in your code?   Also, you say "return", what is the context? are you assigning this var to a text field?  or tracing it? something else?

Comment: URLVariables are encoded, that's why it looks that way.  Decode them to get it back to normal

Comment: I'm little new with variables. How can I decode `urlVars.thedate` ?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(String(urlReq.data));`

Comment: Though I don't understand why you want to work with a URLRequest data? Typically once you assign it, you send it on it's way and don't bother with it again.

Comment: I'll edit my post with comments in order to show you what I want to do. Meanwhile, I did `decodeURIComponent(String(urlReq.data));` then `trace(urlReq.data);` but it still returns : `thedate=25%2F12%2F15`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96839/discussion-between-user3094896-and-badfeelingaboutthis).

Comment: If you're trying to access the data returned from PHP,  you'd do (once the load complete) `loader.data.property` - where property is the var from php.  There is no reason to work with URL request data beyond setting it once to send to your PHP page. If you need to decode what was sent to PHP from AS3, you can use PHP's `urldecode` method. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: At any rate, you can just do:  `trace(urlReq.data.data);` to get your untouched value from the URLVariables object.

Comment: Thx. What I'm trying to do, first, is to send a date to my php. My php begins with `$thedate = $_POST['thedate'];` But my AS3 is not sending the date in a good format. PhP is waiting for `d/m/y` format, and it seems that my AS3 is sending `"d%2Fm%2Fy"`. So the PhP doesn't understand... So I'll try to decode in php but I'd prefer to directly send the `$thedate` in the proper format.

Comment: You need to change the url requests content type to something else then.  I'm very rusty with PHP though and don't recall what works best.  Most people use urlencoded vars though.

Comment: Thx. I will post another question as I've progressed but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3094896 There is no problem with your code, and if you've used your date value in your PHP script you will see that's well formatted : `25/12/15`. You can verify that be returning that value to your AS3 script or write it to a file ...